# How can I find out what events are attached to HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to understand more about jQuery and I'm finding one thing I would like to do is to be able to find out what events are attached to elements. Is there some way using the debugger in IE or Firebug that I can find this out. I don't mean by looking at the source code. What I would like to do is to see events in the same way as I can check out CSS properties with firebug.

Answer (score 6):

Try FireQuery for FireFox

http://firequery.binaryage.com/

When you inspect the elements in FireBug, it shows you all of the events attached to the element.

Answer (score 3):

simply execute `jQuery('#elem_id').data('events');` in the `firebug console`, it will list all the `events` `bound` to the `elements`.

Comment: That's only if they were set using jquery, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can see it with Opera Dragonfly too, just inspect the element and go to properties tab on the inspect sidebar:

[image: Dragonfly screenshot]